# Creating a plugin for Sublime Text 3 in a native language with no python code

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I browse the source code of some of the packages in Sublime Text 3 and I see a single file in a directory and that file has extenstion "so" and nothing else. I wonder, is that a real compiled file created in a native language such as C++? Is it possible to create a plugin for Sublime Text 3 in a native language with no python code?

Answer (score 2):

Python allows you to implement modules in native C and C++, but the API that you use to interface with sublime plugins only supports Python.

That means that while you could conceivably write the bulk of your plugin in one of those languages and not Python, you still need to write the Python part that glues the native code and Sublime together.

Doing so would also require you to compile your native code for all of the Sublime platforms (Linux, Windows and MacOS) and presumably also a 32 and 64 bit version to cover all user possibilities.

As such it's probably not a great idea unless you need to expose some bit of functionality that can't already be done in simple, portable Python code. Even the [Python documentation on extending with C/C++](https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/extending.html) recommends that you not do this if you don't have to.

Comment: take the plugin "bz2" for sublime text 3, go to its source directory. where are the python files? what are those "so" files for?

Comment: That's not a sublime plugin, that's a module that provides bz2 support to python code.